# if condition is not working in php

Tags: php, if-statement

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($photoData['data'])-1;$i++){
    echo $id = $photoData['data'][$i]['tags']['data'][0]['id'];
    $id2 =  $photoData['data'][$i]['tags']['data'][1]['id'];
    if($id == $fbID){
        $photos .= "<div style='float:left;margin:25px;'><a href='crop.php?url=".$photoData['data'][$i]['source']."'><img src='".$photoData['data'][$i]['picture']."'/></a></div>";
    }else{
        $photos = 'We cant find any photo tagged with you, go back and select another album';
    }
}
```

here `$photoData` is an array, and `$fbID` is facebook user id.

I just print `$id` which matches the `$fbID` , but it's not entering the `if` condition.

I also check both the variable (`$id` and `$fbID`) type using `gettype()`. Both the variable is in same type string only.  But it's not matching.

Can any one help me to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You know that you are changing the value of `$id` at the second row of your code, right?

Comment: @Emil Vikstrom that $id2 , its not $id.

Comment: Use `var_dump($id);` and `var_dump($fbID);` and tell as about that, not what you think the variables contain.

Comment: string(9) "581412726" for both outputted

Comment: try to use `trim` on both `$id` and `$fbID`

Comment: please `var_dump( $photoData['data'] );` and update your question with the results.

Comment: Try to modify "$photos = 'We cant" with "$photos .= 'We cant" (notice the DOT)!

Comment: can you please update the code with how $fbID is being set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A perfect example of a simple error you miss when getting code-blind.

The 2nd line

```
echo $id = $photoData['data'][$i]['tags']['data'][0]['id'];
```

should be

```
/* assign value to variable */
$id = $photoData['data'][$i]['tags']['data'][0]['id'];

/* if you really wanted that, echo the variable AFTER it is assigned */
echo($id);
```

as it's cleaner.

**UPDATE**

Use

```
var_dump($id);
var_dump($fbID);
```

and look at the results. If one (or both) say something like

```
 string(9)
```

it shows that variable holds a string, not an integer. To compare strings correctly, you have to change

```
 if($id == $fbID){
```

to

```
 if($id === $fbID){
```

or even failsafer (making sure they're strings)

```
 if(''.$id === ''.$fbID){
```

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE 2**

And I'm not sure if it's intended, but

```
$photos = 'We cant
```

could also be

```
$photos .= 'We cant
```

as it's easy to miss a dot. But that depends on the rest of your code. ;)

Comment: for testing purpose only i gave echo and checked by removing echo .It still not working

Comment: this is wrong.  you can echo a variable assignment.  think about how while loops work. `while ( $row = $query->fetch() )`  it's the same concept, the value is both assigned and used at that spot in the code.  Just to be certain, I did test this before commenting.

Comment: You could change "count($photoData['data'])-1" to "(count($photoData['data'])-1)" to be safe on that one too. The rest of your snippet looks flawless. To debug, try adding "var_dump($id);" without the quotes. It will show you what PHP thinks $id contains. It's always better than a simple echo to pin down bugs as "var_dump" also shows objects (like classes). In fact, I would test all variables ($id, $fbID, $id2 and $photoData) and check if they all contain what they should contain. You'll pretty soon see what variable "doesn't work as expected". Probably "$fbID" or "$photoData"...

Comment: @Tim G : just because it works, doesn't mean it's good coding practice. Also, I wouldn't compare "while" with "echo", even when the variable handling is the same.

Comment: Thinking of it, change "if($id == $fbID){" to "if($id === $fbID){" with 3 instead of 2 "=" characters, just in case $id or $fbID are strings. 2 of those only compare numbers, but 3 of those handle both strings AND integers. BTW: it would've been great if you would have posted how $fbID is constructed.

Comment: @Nathan Sri: if "string(9)" is either $id or $fbID, you have to use 3 '=' signs since you're trying to compare strings. Now let me hear you say... "works". ;)

Comment: @e-sushi I'm not trying to pick a fight.  It's obvious the echo was there just for debugging purposes - it's not a coding practice he's definitely engaged in.  the reason your answer didn't help him is because your answer was patently _wrong_.  it's nothing personal, and I didn't down-vote your answer for it, but it's demonstrably wrong.

Comment: @NathanSri  you do **not** have to use 3 '=' signs for comparing strings. 3 '=' signs enforces type checking on compares.  sigh

Comment: @Tim G: no offense either. I think we've narrowed it down anyway... it looks like a failing string comparison that won't work with "==" but will work with "===". Peace!

Comment: the data is already a string.  reference the OP's comment above:

Comment: @Tim G: only 1 variable (unidentified by OP) is a string. The other is unknown uptil now. So OP is comparing a "string" with WHAT? Now enlighten us with your wisdom by guessing the unknown as long as OP doesn't reveal what variable was identified. It could've been $id2 for what it's worth. Just saying...

Comment: e-sushi it work after adding ''.$id === ''.$fbID thank you so much +10 thank you :)

Comment: @Tim G - don't feel silly, I'll have "one of those days" too sooner or later. Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following line looks a litte strange:

```
  echo $id = $photoData['data'][$i]['tags']['data'][0]['id'];
```

Try changing it to:

```
  // assignment
  $id = $photoData['data'][$i]['tags']['data'][0]['id'];
  // print statement
  echo $id;
```

***EDIT***

You could also try to remove any trailing whitespaces from both variables:

```
  if(trim($id) == trim($fbID)){
        $photos .= "<div style='float:left;margin:25px;'><a href='crop.php?url=".$photoData['data'][$i]['source']."'><img src='".$photoData['data'][$i]['picture']."'/></a></div>";
    }else{
        $photos = 'We cant find any photo tagged with you, go back and select another album';
    }
```

Comment: And if you use `var_dump` on both your variables, do you get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

[edit]

The selected answer provides a lot of misinformation.  I have a problem understanding how making a comparison more strict makes the code work.  You'd think just the opposite.

PHP Manual:

```
$a == $b    Equal   TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type. (introduced in PHP 4)
```

I still stand by my answer - I think I was on the right track... but we'll never know.

---

I believe the problem lies in the `else` portion of your code.

I reformatted the code so I could make sure you didn't have any problems with mismatched braces (you didn't).

Try the following code.  FYI - I removed $id2 since you weren't using it in the code you supplied.

```
echo "Looking for: {$fbID}\n";
$photos = '';
for( $i=0; $i<=count( $photoData['data'] ); $i++ )
{
    $id = $photoData['data'][$i]['tags']['data'][0]['id'];
    echo $id . ($id == $fbID )?' matches':' DOES NOT MATCH' . "<br>\n";

    if( $id == $fbID )
    {
        $photos .= "<div style='float:left;margin:25px;'><a href='crop.php?url=".$photoData['data'][$i]['source']."'><img src='".$photoData['data'][$i]['picture']."'/></a></div>";
    }
    else
    {
        $photos = 'We cant find any photo tagged with you, go back and select another album';
        break; // if you don't break, then you're possibly overwriting anything that's been added in the "true" portion of the if statement.
    }
}
```

[edit]

Two loops will help here.  There may be a way to refactor this down to a single loop, but this should work.

```
echo "Looking for: {$fbID}<br>\n";
$items = array();

for( $i=0; $i<=count( $photoData['data'] ); $i++ )
{
    $id = $photoData['data'][$i]['tags']['data'][0]['id'];
    echo $id . ($id == $fbID )?' matches':' DOES NOT MATCH' . "<br>\n";

    if( $id == $fbID )
    {
        $items[] = $photoData['data'][$i];
    }
}

$photos = 'We cant find any photo tagged with you, go back and select another album';
if ( count( $items ) )
{

    foreach( $items )
    {
        $photos .= '<div style="float:left;margin:25px;"><a href="crop.php?url=' . $item['source'] . '"><img src="' . $item['picture'] . '"/></a></div>';
    }
}

echo $photos;
```

Comment: it comes from a array which contain facebook user id

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't thought through the data format carefully.  I'm editing my answer with new code - try it and see if it helps.

Comment: still getting 'DOES NOT MATCH'

Comment: can you do a var_dump( $data ) at the top of your code from your original question and update your question with it?

Comment: I would expect that you will see "DOES NOT MATCH" because not all photos will match.  That's just debugging output.  Do you see any that say "matches" ?

Comment: i just edited the code above - I had not done the final foreach loop correctly.  you might try that.

Comment: thanks for helping it's working by adding ''.$id === ''.$fbID finally.

Comment: I have to know... how are you setting $fbID?

Comment: i am getting via function parameter